# minmax evaluation with alpha beta pruning

Tags: c++, algorithm, ai, chess

I'm making some small board game and wanted to code a very simple greed AI with this algorithm. It turns out it doesn't play the most greedy moves, it is simply not working. I'd appreciate any comments around this code.

First, the position evaluation functions are:

```
uint8_t get_piece_value(PKind kind)
{
    switch (kind) {
    case PKind::FIRST:
        return 10;
    case PKind::SECOND:
        return 30;
    case PKind::THIRD:
        return 35;
    case PKind::FORTH:
        return 100;
}

int get_position_value(const Position& position)
{
    int value;

    for (auto var : position.pieces) {

        if (var.id.color == position.turnToPlay) {
            value += get_piece_value(var.id.kind);
            continue;
        }
        
        value -= get_piece_value(var.id.kind);

    }

    return value;
}
```

Now this is the function I use to get the valid moves:

```
std::vector<PMove> get_ALL_valid_moves(const Position& position)
{
    std::vector<PMove> allMoves;

    for (auto piece : position.pieces)
    {
        if (piece.id.color == position.turnToPlay) {
            auto validMoves = get_valid_moves(piece);

            if (validMoves.size() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (auto var : validMoves) {
                allMoves.push_back(var);
            }
        } else {
            assert(("Wrong color passed to get ALL valid moves!!\n"));
        }
    }

    return allMoves;
}
```

Next, here are the minmax functions:

````
constexpr int MAX_EVAL = 9999;
constexpr int MIN_EVAL = -MAX_EVAL;

///Minmax evaluation with alpha beta pruning
int minmax_ab(const Position newposition, int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool isMaximizer) 
{
    if (depth == 0) {
        return get_position_value(newposition);
    }

    std::vector<PMove> validMoves;

    validMoves = get_ALL_valid_moves(newposition);

    if (validMoves.size() == 0) {
        return get_position_value(newposition);
    }

    if (isMaximizer) {
        for (auto move : validMoves) {
            alpha  = std::max(alpha, minmax_ab(make_position(newposition, move), depth - 1, alpha, beta, false) );
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                return beta;
            }
        }
        return alpha;

    } else {
        for (auto move : validMoves) {
            beta = std::min(beta, minmax_ab(make_position(newposition, move), depth - 1, alpha, beta, true) );
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                return alpha;
            }
        }
        return beta;
    }

}

PMove minmax_root(const Position& position, const int depth)
{

    std::vector<PMove> validMoves = get_ALL_valid_moves(position);
    /// assume the starting value of the last valid move for best move
    PMove bestmove = validMoves.front();

    int besteval = get_position_value(make_position(position, bestmove));

    int eval = MIN_EVAL;

    for (auto move : validMoves) {
        eval = minmax_ab(make_position(position, move), depth - 1, MIN_EVAL, MAX_EVAL, false);

        if (eval > besteval) {
            besteval = eval;
            bestmove = move;
        }
    }

    return bestmove;
}
```
````

Comment: I’m very much looking forward to reviews of this - I developed an alpha-beta-pruning too, and have been debugging it for months… can’t find my errors.

Comment: I am sorry, but the code which _is simply not working_ is strictly off-topic here.